# How to organize row wise results in column wise results SQL

Tags: sql

I will spare you of the details about my journey, but as you can see I'm really new in SQL, and I'm trying to get my head around how to make queries etc. My question is regarding the following snippet

```
select 
(select count ("code_id")
from example_table  where "code_id" = 3), 
(select 3 as ecoregion),
(select count ("code_id")
from example_table  where "code_id" = 4), 
(select 4 as ecoregion),
(select count ("code_id")
from example_table  where "code_id" = 5), 
(select 5 as ecoregion)
```

The problem is that generates multiple columns with the same name (one for count and one
for the number of elements aliased "ecoregion"). My question is: How can I modify
the code snippet so I will end up having only two columns, one called count and the other
ecoregion and all the results of the queries under them?

Comment: Hello @RogerAlmengor, I see you are new but we need some help from you too. What database do you use ? For example I use Oracle database.

Comment: Hi @VBoka, thank you very much for your reply. Well I installed PostgreSQL12, and I'm using DBeaver 21.3.4. for making my queries in the database using the SQL Edit console. I hope this is enough information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `case when` like in this example:

```
select case when code_id = 3 then
            count (code_id) 
       when code_id = 4 then
            count (code_id) 
       when code_id = 5 then
            count (code_id)
       end "count",
       case when code_id = 3 then
            '3'
       when code_id = 4 then
            '4'
       when code_id = 5 then
            '5'
       end "ecoregion"
from example_table
group by code_id
```

Here you can check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1b52b16d4b1b816ef223388db0c5cf19)

Answer (score 2):

```
select code_id as ecoregion, count(*) as "count"
from T
where code_id in (3, 4, 5)
group by code_id
```

Comment: Hi @RogerAlmengor, this is the correct answer if the ecoregion will be the same as code_id and not mine... You do not need anything else but this....

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union.asp) to attach rows of 2/more `SELECT` statements.

```
select count ("code_id"), 3 as ecoregion
from example_table  where "code_id" = 3

UNION

select count ("code_id"), 4 as ecoregion
from example_table  where "code_id" = 4

UNION

select count ("code_id"), 5 as ecoregion
from example_table  where "code_id" = 5
```

There is also [UNION ALL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union_all.asp), which allows duplicate rows.

Considering your case, I'd suggest you go with the `UNION` as it is fairly an easier concept than the `CASE WHEN.`
You'll get to the `CASE WHEN` too.